# Apply same effect to all elements with the same tabindex on focus of one of them

Tags: css

On my last one, I asked how to make unfocusable elements become focus-able in the means of css selector. The answer is to use tabindex.

Now I wanted that, when an element with the selector is focused (clicked), the other element selected by the selector also got the effect. It may sound strange, but I could do that a long time ago accidentally, but I forgot how.

Here is the jsfiddle example :
http://jsfiddle.net/s4nji/xa8j4/

Comment: don't believe it's possible without javascript or setting a common class, which would require some sort of page load or javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This selector does the trick:

```
li[tabindex='1']:focus ~ li[tabindex='1'], li[tabindex='1']:focus {
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/v5sYT/)'s an example.

It only selects both when you focus on the first one though.

This only works in CSS3 since we're using the general sibling selector.

When the first one is focused, it selects the second one with the same `tabindex` and adds the background. The second `li[tabindex='1']:focus` is to apply the background to the currently focused one too.

The general sibling selector can only select succeeding elements with the same parent. CSS can't travel up the DOM, unfortunately. For this reason, the only way to have it work backwards too would be to use Javascript.

Comment: Nice trick! But shouldn't the html not duplicate tab indexes to begin with?

Comment: @Scott: Duplicate tab indexes are fine. What happens is that elements with the same tabindex get grouped together in the tabbing. So in this case, the first will be the first element to gain focus when tabbed and the fourth will be the second. Then it jumps to tabindex 2 and works the same way.

Comment: Thanks. I realize tabbing jumps with similar tabindexes. I've just always followed the rule of no duplicate indexes. Still a nifty trick that will have me looking into CSS3 siblings. Thanks