# :last-child pseudo class confusion

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

In [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s4nji/x2KFb/), the last `.tab` class doesn't get the correct `border-radius` effect (top right rounded corner).

I think I have my logic correct in saying `:last-child` selects the last `.tab` of `.tabbed` in this case.

What am I doing wrong?

CSS:

```
body {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px; }

.tabbed {
    height: 550px;
}

.tabbed .tab {
    padding: 6px 14px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    border-radius: 0px;
    border-left-width: 0;
    float: left;
}

.tabbed .tab:first-child {
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 0;
    border-left-width: 1px;
}

.tabbed .tab:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 3px 0 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class='tabbed'>
    <li class='tab'>Menu 1</li>
    <li class='tab'>Menu 2</li>
    <li class='tab'>Menu 3</li>
    <li class='tab'>Menu 4</li>
    <li class='tab'>Menu 5</li>
    <li> <br/><br/> </li>
    <li class='dummy'>Content 1</li>
    <li class='dummy'>Content 2</li>
    <li class='dummy'>Content 3</li>
    <li class='dummy'>Content 4</li>
    <li class='dummy'>Content 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I created a jsfiddle for you and others to see and work with using the above code :) http://jsfiddle.net/tFhBh/

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Why? There's already one linked in the question.

Comment: I increased the border-radius to 30 for demo debug clarity purposes

Comment: Andrew - because I didn't read the question carefully enough

Comment: Here's how i would [solve it](http://jsfiddle.net/nicerobot/x2KFb/9/).

Comment: If you remove everything but the ul and li's, get rid of that remainder code with the other lists it works...

Comment: Looks like you have to close the `ul.tabbed` after menu 5...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a comment, you state: "It needs to be on the same ul parent. Or another ul, below the last li on the first ul." If that is so, then do this:

```
<ul class='tabbed'>
    <li class='tab'>Menu 1</li>
    <li class='tab'>Menu 2</li>
    <li class='tab'>Menu 3</li>
    <li class='tab'>Menu 4</li>
    <li class='tab'>Menu 5</li>
    <li>
    <ul>
    <li class='dummy'>Content 1</li>
    <li class='dummy'>Content 2</li>
    <li class='dummy'>Content 3</li>
    <li class='dummy'>Content 4</li>
    <li class='dummy'>Content 5</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then this css (with modern browsers):

```
.tabbed {
height: 550px; }

.tabbed .tab {
padding: 6px 14px;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
border-radius: 0px;
border-left-width: 0;
float: left; }

.tabbed .tab:first-child {
border-radius: 3px 0 0 0;
border-left-width: 1px; }

.tabbed .tab:nth-last-child(2) {
border-radius: 0 3px 0 0; }

.tabbed li:last-child {
   clear: left;
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x2KFb/6/).

Comment: Ahh, never thought of nth-last-child(2)!
Thanks a lot!! :D

Answer (score 5):

According to this [documentation](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/firstchild.html):

> The :first-child pseudo class means "if this element is the first
>   child of its parent". :last-child means "if this element is the last
>   child of its parent". Note that only element nodes (HTML tags) count,
>   these pseudo-classes ignore text nodes.

*See also [W3C doc](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/%3alast-child)*

It is not applied in your case because the last `.tab` is not the last child of the parent ul.

If you create two lists, then the css is applied as expected.

Comment: Please include a link to the documentation you're quoting.

Comment: Yes, the only way to do this is to make two lists (*and why not?*). The two categories of `<li>`s that I see clearly don't belong in the same list, and besides, `<li> <br/><br/> </li>` is complete nonsense in terms of semantics and shouldn't even be there to begin with.

Comment: Continuing from the last topic I started, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692442/apply-same-effect-to-all-elements-with-the-same-tabindex-on-focus-of-one-of-them

It needs to be on the same ul parent.
Or another ul, below the last li on the first ul

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [Didier G.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693357/last-child-pseudo-class-confusion/8693416#8693416), what you should really be using here is the [`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/:first-of-type) & [`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/:last-of-type) pseudo selectors. However, the [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/:nth-of-type) selector (and its similar shorthand versions) does not appear to support using a classname for searching, only selecting, e.g. the following will select the first child of `.tabbed`, if and only if it has the class `.tab`:

```
.tabbed .tab:first-of-type
```

whereas this will select the first child of `.tabbed` that is of type `li`:

```
.tabbed li:first-of-type
```

I cannot find any reference explicitly stating this behavior, but it is vaguely implied in the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-of-type-pseudo):

> The `:nth-of-type(an+b)` pseudo-class notation represents an element that has `an+b-1` siblings with the same expanded element name

Where an *expanded element name* is the tag name, and cannot be a class or ID selector.

You can see this behavior [live on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wbaHr/2/).

Comment: The `:*-of-type` pseudo-classes match based on, well, [element type](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#type-selectors), which means pretty much the same thing as element name. Additionally, the selector `.tab:first-of-type` does mean something: it selects any first child element of its type if it also has the class `tab`.

Comment: @BoltClock This doesn't appear to actually be true, though: http://jsfiddle.net/wbaHr/. Behaves the same in Chrome 16, Safari 5.1, & Firefox 9.

Comment: @BoltClock Oh wait, I see what you're saying, I'll update my answer.

Comment: .tabbed li:last-of-type still affect the last li, .dummy, not .tab ones :(

Comment: `.tabbed .tab:first-of-type` = `.tabbed *.tab:first-of-type`

Answer (score 1):

[Here's how i would do it](http://jsfiddle.net/nicerobot/x2KFb/9/):

```
body {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px; }

.content {clear:both;}
.tall {
    height: 550px;
}

.tabbed .tab {
padding: 6px 14px;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
float: left; }

.tabbed .tab:first-child {
border-radius: 3px 0 0 0;
border-left-width: 1px; }

.tabbed .tab:last-child {
border-radius: 0 3px 0 0; }
```

And because i think it seems inappropriate to include the *content* within a class called `tabbed`, change the HTML to be structured as:

```
<div class="tall">
<ul class='tabbed'>
    <li class='tab'>Menu 1</li>
    <li class='tab'>Menu 2</li>
    <li class='tab'>Menu 3</li>
    <li class='tab'>Menu 4</li>
    <li class='tab'>Menu 5</li>
</ul>
<ul class="content">
    <li class='dummy'>Content 1</li>
    <li class='dummy'>Content 2</li>
    <li class='dummy'>Content 3</li>
    <li class='dummy'>Content 4</li>
    <li class='dummy'>Content 5</li>
</ul>
</div>
<hr/><!-- just here to show you the height remains -->
```